# unable to connect to internet through lan

Tags: wireless, lan

I am connected both lan cable and wifi with ubuntu. while lan connects to a local gigabit network with no internet gateway.  I cannot ping google.com or any address  in internet.

-> if I unplug network cable or "ifconfig eth0 down" than wifi network forks fine. 
-> I can ping to any local ip connected in both network.

Comment: Does any other machine on your network have internet access?

Comment: You write yourself that wired LAN isn't connected to the internet. Why do you think you should be able to ping google.com? Sounds like your local network isn't configured right.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use your wireless connection while you are connected to the local lan.

The problem is, when you connect to both, wlan AND lan, the networkmanager sets one default route, normally the one from the local lan. What you have to do is deleting the default route of you local lan, and adding the default route of your wlan device. You can find this out which default route is set by typing:

```
route -n
```

it shows you something like this:

```
0.0.0.0         10.16.0.1       0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.16.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1      0        0 eth0
192.168.20.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     2      0        0 wlan0
```

as you can see my default route leads through 10.16.0.1.

deleting default route (in my case):

```
route del default gw 10.16.0.1
```

adding default route to the wlan connection (in my case):

```
route add default gw 192.168.20.1
```

after all it should look like this (in my case):

```
0.0.0.0         192.168.20.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
10.16.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1      0        0 eth0
192.168.20.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     2      0        0 wlan0
```